# Suspending fails when a USB mouse is connected

Tags: ubuntu, usb, suspend, acpi

When I try to suspend my Ubuntu 14.04 (with KDE environment) using

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

it fails unless I disconnect USB devices, e.g. USB mice and flash drives.

Is there a way to solve this problem?